# Instruments result automated parsing

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, instruments

I am working on automating my iOS project's build process using Jenkins and `xcodebuild` command line tool. I am also able to test the application on simulator using UIAutomation testing scripts (`instruments` command line utility). But I would like to use other instruments like Time Profiler, Leaks, etc.. along with the automation to automatically test for irregular behavior.

Although I can make a custom template and run it with automation, but the problem is I can not parse the results of these other Instruments. Is there a way, for example, to know that there is a leak in my code, and trigger an email (from jenkins)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (I've done it), but it is terribly complicated to do *well*. You need something to translate the Instruments results plist to something Jenkins can understand. You can use XSLT (I wouldn't recommend it), or write a script in perl/python/etc.

The Jenkins XCode plugin is an excellent tool for automating Xcode from Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin

That aside, building a CI environment around UIAutomation is doable, but there are a lot of gotchas - the Jenkins user has to have the correct set of permissions to use the dev tools, has to be in the right group, and has to be logged into the UI for the simulator to run correctly from Instruments. Make sure you can get that far before you invest too much time into parsing the output of the Instruments run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already parsing the plist file generated by UIAutomation instrument using a small python script that I wrote. The problem is with other instruments, that do not produce a plist or some other parse-able file, or do they?

Comment: They do produce plists as results, yes. The data inside them is going to be very different, however, and may not be something you can easily transform into something else. You can take one of your existing UIAutomation tests, add a Leaks instrument to the document, and save that as a trace template. Run Instruments from the command line using that trace template, that will give you an idea of what it produces as output.